# Collision isn't working properly?

Tags: c#, collision

I'm working on a survival like game and i have two types of collision, 1 being enemies on the player and bullet on the enemies. I also have a health bar and for some reason after the picbox is removed the health still goes down like the enemies are interacting with the player.

```
private void checkbulletcollsion()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < bulletlistupright.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int u = 0; u < infectedlistdownleft.Count; u++)
        {
            if (bulletlistupright[i].Bounds.IntersectsWith(infectedlistdownleft[u].Bounds))
            {
                this.Controls.Remove(infectedlistdownleft[u]);
                this.Controls.Remove(bulletlistupright[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is one block of the code for the bullet collision (all the code is the same for all 8 directions)

```
for (int i = 0; i < infectedlistupright.Count; i++)
{
    if (infectedlistupright[i].Bounds.IntersectsWith(picplayer.Bounds))
    {
        infectedcount6 = 0;

        if (infectedcounter % 15 == 0)
        {
            health--;
        }

        infectedcounter++;
    }                
}
```

this is the code for the collision between the enemy and the player

Answer (score 1):

Even though you have removed the UI control, you have not removed it from your `infectedlist*` array.

Comment: Just another hint, If you've removed it within your checkbulletcollsion loop, make sure you're not skipping the next check (ie you need to reduce your loop index too)